# Python: sorting dictionary of dictionaries

Tags: python, sorting, dictionary

I have a dict (which is also a key of a larger dict) of dicts that looks like

```
wd[wc][dist][True]={'course': {'#': 1, 'Fisher': 4.0},
 'i': {'#': 1, 'Fisher': -0.2222222222222222},
 'of': {'#': 1, 'Fisher': 2.0},
 'will': {'#': 1, 'Fisher': 3.5}}
```

I want to sort the key words (at the highest level) by their corresponding 'Fisher' value...
so that the output looks like

```
wd[wc][dist][True]={'course': {'Fisher': 4.0, '#': 1}, 'will': {'Fisher': 3.5, '#': 1}, 'of': {'Fisher': 2.0, '#': 1}, 'i': {'Fisher': -0.2222222222222222, '#': 1}}
```

I've tried working with items() and sorted() but can't work it out...
Please help me out :(

Comment: Unfortunately you can't sort a dictionary, it's unordered. Read this great post for pointers on how to do it: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/613183/python-sort-a-dictionary-by-value

Comment: 2021: for Python >=3.7 the language specifies that dictionaries are order-preserving, and CPython implements this.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/613183/how-do-i-sort-a-dictionary-by-value

Answer (score 40, accepted):

You can't sort a dict, but can get a sorted list of keys, values or (key,values) pairs.

```
>>> dic = {'i': {'Fisher': -0.2222222222222222, '#': 1}, 'of': {'Fisher': 2.0, '#': 1}, 'will': {'Fisher': 3.5, '#': 1}, 'course': {'Fisher': 4.0, '#': 1}}

>>> sorted(dic.items(), key=lambda x: x[1]['Fisher'], reverse=True)
[('course', {'Fisher': 4.0, '#': 1}),
 ('will', {'Fisher': 3.5, '#': 1}),
 ('of', {'Fisher': 2.0, '#': 1}),
 ('i', {'Fisher': -0.2222222222222222, '#': 1})
]
```

Or create an [`collections.OrderedDict`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html?highlight=ordereddict#ordereddict-examples-and-recipes)(introduced in Python 2.7) after getting the sorted (key,value) pairs:

```
>>> from collections import OrderedDict
>>> od = OrderedDict(sorted(dic.items(), key=lambda x: x[1]['Fisher'], reverse=True))
>>> od
OrderedDict([
('course', {'Fisher': 4.0, '#': 1}),
('will', {'Fisher': 3.5, '#': 1}),
('of', {'Fisher': 2.0, '#': 1}),
('i', {'Fisher': -0.2222222222222222, '#': 1})
])
```

For your dictionary, try this:

```
>>> from collections import OrderedDict
>>> dic = wd[wc][dist][True]
>>> wd[wc][dist][True]= OrderedDict(sorted(dic.items(), key=lambda x: x[1]['Fisher'], reverse=True))
```

Comment: Note that [`OrderedDict`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html?highlight=ordereddict#ordereddict-examples-and-recipes) is only for Python versions 2.7 and above.

Comment: using items() results in KeyError... why could that be?

Comment: @CosmicRabbitMediaInc One of your dictionaries may not have the `Fisher` key, is that correct? Try `all('Fisher' in d[k] for k in d)` and post output

Comment: @jamylak Ive tried print dic.items() but it alone results in key error... is it still related to fisher key? btw my dic itself is also a key of a larger dic..

Comment: @CosmicRabbitMediaInc This answer works fine, your data structure is not a dictionary

Comment: @jamylak sorry I have a very clumsy understanding of dict and list... How could the answer be modified to fit my case?

Comment: @CosmicRabbitMediaInc Then try `larger_dict[key].items()`, or post the larger `dict` in question body.

Comment: @AshwiniChaudhary sorry for the confusion. I modified the question. Your new suggestion still results in key error...

Comment: @AshwiniChaudhary that worked magically. Thank you so much for saving me :)

Answer (score 5):

If you just need the keys in order, you can get a list like this

```
dic = {'i': {'Fisher': -0.2222222222222222, '#': 1}, 'of': {'Fisher': 2.0, '#': 1}, 'will': {'Fisher': 3.5, '#': 1}, 'course': {'Fisher': 4.0, '#': 1}}
sorted(dic, key=lambda k: dic[k]['Fisher'])
```

if 'Fisher' might be missing, you can use this to move those entries last

```
sorted(dic, key=lambda x:dic[x].get('Fisher', float('inf')))
```

or `'-inf'` to place them at the beginning

Comment: How would you remove the entries completely if they don't have 'Fisher'?