# Sorting dictionary inside dictionary

Tags: python, python-3.x

How to sort dictionary inside dictionary?

```
dic={doc1: {'qq': 5, 'ww': 6, 'gg': 2}, doc2: {'xx': 1, 'cc': 9, 'hh': 4}}
```

I want it to be like this (sorted desc on values of inner dictionary)

```
dic={doc1: {'ww': 6, 'qq': 5, 'gg': 2}, doc2: {'cc': 9, 'hh': 4, 'xx': 1}}
```

I've looked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16412563/python-sorting-dictionary-of-dictionaries), but that seems to solve only particular problem.  I have thousands of keys (doc3, doc4,...), so I want something more generic.

Thanks

**EDIT**

I figured it out. Since I can't post solution solution is here:

```
import operator
for q in dic:
    dummydict=dic[q]
    sorted_d = sorted(dummydict.items(), key=operator.itemgetter(1), reverse=True)
    sortedDic[q]=dict(sorted_d)
```

I understand that you might say that dictionary will not necessarily preserve its order. I run on 3.6.4, and it preserves

Comment: Dictionaries are not ordered data structures. Your question doesn't have any clear meaning.

Comment: Is there any way to accomplish above task? @JohnColeman

Comment: @Hamms that is 1 dictionary, here I have dictionary inside dictionary

Comment: The task that you want to accomplish is ill-defined. What do you mean by "sorting a dictionary?"

Comment: @JohnColeman , I want the output where for each 1st key, second keys are sorted based on its values (see output example). Eventually, I want to create a dict where for each 1st key I have top 2 of 2nd key. For example {doc1:{ww:6,qq:5},doc2{cc:9,hh:4}}

Comment: @EricKlaus Ho about mine?

Comment: Are you using Python 3.6 or later? Dictionaries do not preserve insertion order in older versions of Python.

Comment: Sure 3.6 version

Answer (score 0):

Try dictionary comprehension:

```
>>> dic={'doc1': {'qq': 5, 'ww': 6, 'gg': 2}, 'doc2': {'xx': 1, 'cc': 9, 'hh': 4}}
>>> {k:dict(sorted(v.items(),key=lambda x: x[1],reverse=True)) for k,v in dic.items()}
{'doc1': {'ww': 6, 'qq': 5, 'gg': 2}, 'doc2': {'cc': 9, 'hh': 4, 'xx': 1}}
>>>
```

Comment: It is not generic, that will solve only above 2 keys. I have thousands of keys (doc3,doc4,...,doc1000)

Comment: @EricKlaus What do you mean? That code will work on a dictionary containing any number of dictionaries, assuming you run it on Python 3.6+. It won't work on arbitrarily nested dicts, though.

Comment: what happens if dict is this? dic={doc1: {'ww': 6, 'qq': 5, 'gg': 2}, doc2: {'cc': 9, 'hh': 4, 'xx': 1},doc3: {'cc': 9, 'hh': 4, 'xx': 1}}. I'll have to add doc3 values too to your script? and then doc4, etc. ? I have thousands of docs, with your solution, script will be million rows length